# EF Core: The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to implement a query in EF Core in which I need to get data where any name in  a string array is contained by the name of the data object. Here is the code sample:

```
            var searchKeys = search.Split(' ');
            var objects = _db.Objects
                .Where(o => searchKeys.Any(k => o.name.Contains(k))))  
                .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                .Select o
```

But the query cannot be translated resulting in the following error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>           .Where(o => __searchKeys_1
>               .Any(k => __Functions_2
>                   .Contains(
>                       _: o.Name, 
>                       propertyReference: k)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
>   to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
>   AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

How can I contruct the query to fix the error?

Comment: Have you checked the link? As the error states that this evaluation is not allowed in ef core 3.0 read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: You effectively want to combine like with in. This is not that easy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since the objects table will contain large volume of data I was hoping I could query one of the properties and compare it partly against the search key. Much like normal search engines do.

Comment: I think you want to replace o.Contains(k) with o.Name.Contains(k).

Comment: just fixed it, was by mistake

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, I could not get Obie's answer to work for me in .Net Core 3.1. Luckily, the [LinqKit NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) has been upgraded for .Net Core. So I defined this extension method:

```
// Where any search predicates are true.
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] predicates)
{
    var orPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var predicate in predicates)
    {
        orPredicate = orPredicate.Or(predicate);
    }
    return q.AsExpandable().Where(orPredicate);
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
var searchKeys = search.Split(' ');
var predicates = searchKeys.Select(k => (Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>)(x => x.Name.Contains(k)));
var objects = _db.Objects
    .WhereAny(predicates.ToArray())
    .OrderBy(o => o.Name);
```

Comment: Worked beautifully with EF Core 5.x

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 var searchKeys = search.Split(' ');
 var objects = _db.Objects
     .Where(o => searchKeys.Any(k => o.Name.Contains(k)))
     .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
     .Select(o => o);
```

Comment: Strange, does it still work if you put .ToList() at the end of the select?

Comment: just tried this and am still getting the err - what version of 3.1 are you running